# Spotify api getting acces token / code

Tags: java, spotify

so I'm trying to use this library [library](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java) 
to access my Spotify account but i can't figure out how i can get an acces token but i can't figure out how i can get the response from the authorization URL I have trayed creating a input stream that access the url and print out the response but i dos not give the right output i have also trayed creating a server with shut receive the response but I'm getting nothing i have never used java server / networking that much so i might have made an error....

```js
public class privat {
    public privat() throws IOException {


        final String clientId = "clientId ";
        final String clientSecret = "clientSecret code ";
        final String redirectUri = "http://localhost:8888/callback";
        final Api api = Api.builder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .redirectURI(redirectUri)
                .build();

/* Set the necessary scopes that the application will need from the user */
        final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("user-read-private", "user-read-email");

/* Set a state. This is used to prevent cross site request forgeries. */
        final String state = "someExpectedStateString";

        String authorizeURL = api.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
        System.out.println(authorizeURL);

/* Continue by sending the user to the authorizeURL, which will look something like
   https://accounts.spotify.com:443/authorize?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/callback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=some-state-of-my-choice
 */


/* Application details necessary to get an access token */
        final String code = "" ;/* where to find this ?? */



        /* Make a token request. Asynchronous requests are made with the .getAsync method and synchronous requests
 * are made with the .get method. This holds for all type of requests. */
        final SettableFuture<AuthorizationCodeCredentials> authorizationCodeCredentialsFuture = api.authorizationCodeGrant(code).build().getAsync();

/* Add callbacks to handle success and failure */
        Futures.addCallback(authorizationCodeCredentialsFuture, new FutureCallback<AuthorizationCodeCredentials>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCodeCredentials) {
    /* The tokens were retrieved successfully! */
                System.out.println("Successfully retrieved an access token! " + authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
                System.out.println("The access token expires in " + authorizationCodeCredentials.getExpiresIn() + " seconds");
                System.out.println("Luckily, I can refresh it using this refresh token! " +     authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());

    /* Set the access token and refresh token so that they are used whenever needed */
                api.setAccessToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
                api.setRefreshToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
    /* Let's say that the client id is invalid, or the code has been used more than once,
     * the request will fail. Why it fails is written in the throwable's message. */
                    System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
                System.out.println(throwable.getStackTrace());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `code` comes as a query parameter to your callback URL once the user authorises your application. You'll need to find a way to grab it from there - you could spin up a web server on `localhost:8888` to get the code from there - or you could instruct the user to copy the code from the query parameters of the redirect URI once they're redirected. You can find more information about the authorisation procedure (looks like either the `authorization code` or `implicit grant` flows will work for you) [on the Spotify Developer site](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).